# QYT KT8900D issue

Tags: transceiver

A very specific issue this one. I bought one of these radios on an impulse because it was cheap but never really used it. Now, during lockdown my club has a nightly net on 2m so I built an antenna and started using it.
The reception was patchy at best on all but the closest people with faint reception and a lot of static.
Then I nudged the power button and it cleared up instantly, crystal audio and very low static. The power button is  a momentary switch that switches on and off with a long press but I cannot find out in the manual what the short press is and if I there is a setting in the menu that will fix this.

Long shot but does anyone know anything about the QYT?

Comment: You might pose your question to the [Two Way Radio Forum](https://www.twowayradioforum.com/). You'll have to sign up to login and post your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't own a KYT8900D, but I did download the manual, and I went over it to see if the power button has a short-press function.  If there is such a function, I wasn't able to find it in the manual.

I find the notion that the radio has a function associated with the power button, not mentioned in the manual, that clears up the reception to be very unlikely.  If there were a function that improves reception for weak signals, then the manual would surely emphasize it for marketing purposes.  I also find the notion of the power button having a secondary function to be unlikely, unless the radio is so crammed with functions that there is no other button to hold the function.  Putting multiple functions on the power button is bad design; hold the button too long, and the radio switches off, which would annoy operators.

I'm just guessing here, but I think that there's an intermittent connection somewhere in your setup, and pressing the button fixes the intermittent connection temporarily.  I suppose that it's possible that the bad connection is in your PL-259 coaxial connector, especially if you soldered it yourself and you don't have much practice soldering PL-259s, but that seems unlikely because pressing one place on the front panel would be unlikely to flex the connection between the coaxial cable and the connector.

The most likely explanation seems to me to be an intermittent connection inside the radio.  The problem could be a cracked surface-mount component, a corroded connector pin, a poor solder joint, etc.  Good quality control can prevent such defects from leaving the factory, but QYT seems to be a company that is new to making radios, and their reputation for quality control seems to be mostly unknown.  You could try pushing on the front panel near the power button.  If that improves the reception, then that would support the intermittent-connection theory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's certainly not an intermittent connection issue as I don't need to touch the radio for the signal to change. Once I press the on button and the quiet station becomes louder I can listen in to the net and the next time the quiet station transmits it is back to quiet and noise. That is what led me to believe that there is a setting or function not mentioned in the manual, it really is a poor manual but that's what you get when you spent pennies I guess. If I wanted a phone book sized manual I should have bought a Yaesu.

Comment: Weird.  Sounds defective to me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found that the noise was due to electric meter telemetry.  Our neighborhood is awash in this.  It is regular, and it disappears on its own in about the same time to give the power button a meaningless quick push!  Rather than push the power button for momentary relief, I 'found' that switching the channel and returning it 'did the trick'!  But, alas, I think it was my imagination and not flipping the channel selector back and forth that was eliminating the static.  A better radio with front end bandpass filter won't suffer this issue.  The QYT lets anything in.  I can transmit much farther than I can receive, and the noise floor rises considerably coming up to Interstate speed.  With the squelch off, this is very noticeable.

Comment: Hi Steve, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  Thanks for sharing your experience with that radio model.